# How to download libcurl3 php5-curl manually then install on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't use apt-get to install it cuz the version of my ubuntu is old but i need to use these
packages, is there any way to download and install them manually?

thanks.

Comment: Don't use old, out of date, unsupported operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

For the php part, try: Quoting http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/wiki/Installation

" Composer is PHP's next generation awesome package manager. Where PEAR usually installed packages 'system wide', composer is geared towards per-project package and dependency management.

To install composer, use :

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Or have a look at http://

getcomposer.org for some more details. "

For libcurl3: depending on the version of ubuntu you are using you could try to find a source package for libcurl3 from a newer version and build a backport yourself. Or find the source and make an unpacked build. I'd recommend the former though, it will be cleaner adn easier to remove or upgrade.